# Queries in EJB QL Collection Member Comparison

Tags: ejbql

I need to write the following sql query, in EJBQL.

```
SELECT * FROM teacher t left join student_class sc on t.id_teacher = p.id_student_class where t.login = 01325 and sc.id_student_class = 3;
```

In the class bean Teacher, there is the following relantionship:

```
@Column(name = "login")
private String mLogin;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "mTeacher", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<StudentClass> mStudentClassList ;
```

I know how start it:

```
SELECT mTeacher FROM Teacher mTeacher INNER JOIN mTeacher.mStudentClassList  mStudentClassList WHERE mTeacher.mLogin = 01325 AND mStudentClassList
```

... ???

Can anyone help me?